# try using the bin/bundle install command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

**This is my gem file**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3’, group: [:development, :test]
# gems required by Heroku
gem ‘pg’, group: :production
gem ‘rails_12factor’, group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', ‘~> 5.0’
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:            https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger       console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the     background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

**This is the error i get when trying to use the bin/bundle install command**

```
LJ$ bin/bundle install --without production

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input - gem 'sass-rails', ‘~> 5.0’
     ^. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/LJ/code/blog/Gemfile:12
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 >  gem 'sass-rails', ‘~> 5.0’
 #  # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

**I can't figure out what the problem is. I am going along with the Rails Crash Course book if that helps.

Comment: You have a bunch of invalid quote characters (‘ and ’). Those need to be replaced with normal single or double-quotes (' or ").

Comment: Can you be a little more specific...like which one is an invalid quote character?

Comment: I did tell you in my comment: ‘ and ’

Comment: Luckily someone else helped me out cause your answer was incorrect. I guess you don't know Rails very well...it's too bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of the invalid quote characters is:

```
gem 'sqlite3’
```

The second ' is an invalid single quote. Notice how it slightly curves in your sample code.

These types of errors usually show up when you edit the text in a text editor like TextEdit. Try fixing the single quotes using a different text editor. Try using something like TextWrangler, SublimeText, or just nano.